# Parsing XML with SimpleXML returns nothing

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm currently trying to parse the MapQuest Traffic API, but when I try to display an incident, nothing appears, and if I do "if empty" in php, it returns empty.

Here's the code:

```
    <?php
    $mysongs = simplexml_load_file("http://www.mapquestapi.com/traffic/v1/incidents?key=Fmjtd%7Cluuan1u2nh%2C2a%3Do5-96rw5u&callback=handleIncidentsResponse&boundingBox=$_GET[a], $_GET[b], $_GET[c], $_GET[d]&filters=construction,incidents&inFormat=kvp&outFormat=xml");
echo $mysongs->Incidents[0]->Incident[0]->fullDesc;
?>
```

The parameters I'm passing: ?a=33.352532499999995&b=-118.2324383&c=34.352532499999995&d=-117.2324383.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Back up a bit. Does your `simplexml_load_file()` call actually even retrieve the XML correctly?

Comment: Also, that URL didn't provide a structure like the one you're trying to access.

Comment: I assume you've removed some kind of key? please **print_r($mysongs);** to see your simplexml object [message] => _This is not a valid key. Please check that you have entered this correctly. If you do not have a key, you can obtain a free key by registering at http://developer.mapquest.com._

Comment: i just tested your code... there is no data in Incidents.. so it shows nothing

Comment: There is data in incidents... I just tested the url... Here's the url (shorted) http://goo.gl/NQ4Qv... And the key I entered works, I believe... Thanks for helping BTW.

Comment: Yes, but here the problem is simplexml_load_file() function not retriving that incident data, if wanna check it use print_r($mysongs);

Comment: @Daya But why isn't it retrieving the data? What can I do to make it work?

Comment: The key I entered is correct...

Comment: Your code, as provided, should have PHP *screaming* about notices and warnings.  You really should crank up your `error_reporting` and either turn `display_errors` on or watch your error log.  Chances are that one of the warnings or notices being hidden is the one explaining what's wrong.

Comment: Errors *are* turned on, I believe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here simplexml_load_file not loading all your xml data so, i created a xml file with name test.xml and then loaded data from test.xml. Now you can print data what you need.

```
<?php


  $a = $_GET['a'];
  $b = $_GET['b'];
  $c = $_GET['c'];
  $d = $_GET['d'];

   $xml_feed_url = 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/traffic/v1/incidents?key=Fmjtd|luuan1u2nh%2C2a%3Do5-96rw5u&callback=handleIncidentsResponse&boundingBox='.$a.','.$b.','.$c.','.$d.'&filters=construction,incidents&inFormat=kvp&outFormat=xml';
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xml_feed_url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $xml = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);


            $xml2 = new SimpleXMLElement($xml); 

            $xml2->asXML("test.xml");
            $xml2->asXML();

    $mysongs = simplexml_load_file("test.xml"); 
    print_r($mysongs);      
?>
```

Comment: What's with the curl and SimpleXMLElement hoop jumping?  [`simplexml_load_file`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_file) can take a URL without a problem.  Perhaps you have not explained what adding these steps actually *does*.

Comment: Thanks, your code works, BUT when I use replace "&boundingBox=33.3525325,%20-118.2324383,%2034.3525325,%20-117.2324383" with "&boundingBox=$_GET[a], $_GET[b], $_GET[c], $_GET[d]", to fetch the parameters, it doesn't work. (The parameters are "?a=33.352532499999995&b=-118.2324383&c=34.352532499999995&d=-117.2324383". Please help me with this. Thank you so much! (I will mark as accept and upvote when this is solved. :))

Comment: @Charles yes, I don't understand either... and that's not the problem either, it always parsed "http://www.mapquestapi.com/traffic/v1/incidents?key=Fmjtd|luuan1u2nh%2C2a%3Do5-96rw5u&callback=handleIncidentsResponse&boundingBox=33.3525325,%20-118.2324383,%2034.3525325,%20-117.2324383&filters=construction,incidents&inFormat=kvp&outFormat=xml," (short url http://goo.gl/NQ4Qv), but not when I replace "&boundingBox=33.3525325,%20-118.2324383,%2034.3525325,%20-117.2324383" with "&boundingBox=$_GET[a], $_GET[b], $_GET[c], $_GET[d]". When I use $_GET in the url, it then doesn't echo anything.

Comment: we cant do that  because we dont know the values of $_GET[lat], $_GET[long]....., if you define that values as in the url you will get it.

Comment: the values of $_GET[a] is 33.352532499999995, the value of $_GET[b] is -118.2324383, the value of $_GET[c] is 34.352532499999995, and the value of $_GET[c] is -117.2324383. Thanks again!

Comment: The URL which I am testing the code at is http://dumbsearch.com/tra.php?a=33.352532499999995&b=-118.2324383&c=34.352532499999995&d=-117.2324383 .

Comment: But can you explain what you did to fix the problem?

Comment: You just passed Variables $_GET[a]..etc.. in a string content, but not in proper format, if  we want to include a sub string in a string data we will follow like this $a ="klm"; $data = "abcdefghij".$a."nop";